# Did the shuttle cost more per launch than a Saturn V (after inflation)?

Tags: politics, economics

I got this one from some political debate; unfortunately no reference to it. I know the shuttle was a boondoggle; but I find it hard to believe it was really that outrageous.

On the other hand, the best attested reports for the per-launch cost of a Saturn yielded over a billion dollars in today's dollars, which is preposterous. (This currently comes up directly on the [google search results page](https://www.google.com/#q=saturn+v+launch+cost&*) for $1.16 billion). I suspect the error is including the large development cost over a production run of only 13 payload-capable boosters with 2 unused. The shuttle's cost given by the [same method](https://www.google.com/#q=space+shuttle+launch+cost&*) yields 450 million which is not obviously out-of-range.

Here's a link for some more reasonable number's on Saturn V https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=6742.0 (yields $565 million per Saturn V; but also yields $200 million for the shuttle). Some of the other numbers on the same page are obviously wrong though so I take the whole thing with a huge grain of salt.

Comment: Might ask on the Space Exploration exchange.  Though I think it could have a place here, there are lots of intelligent people with real-world knowledge there.

Comment: As stands, this is missing a notable claim.  Space Exploration doesn't require notable claims.  Or you could find someone making the title claim and it would work here.

Comment: I agree with @brythan. You need to reference "some political debate."

Comment: I can find variations of this claim, most of them having to do with a "dollars per pound" comparison, but I can't seem to find one this specific. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_the_Space_Shuttle_program): "Space Shuttle incremental per-pound launch costs ultimately turned out to be considerably higher than those of expendable launchers." Not sure if that's close enough to count here.

Comment: I think this is a question worth considering, but it would be a tricky one to answer as you'd have to consider research and development costs, setup and infrastructure costs and the costs of actually flying a mission.  This is going to be complicated by the fact that the Saturn V's payloads were all expendable, whereas the core Shuttle components except for the tank could be reused by varying degrees.

Comment: 1.16 billion for 140 tons of payload to LEO equals ~8286$/kg for the Saturn V. Which is less then half the cost per kg then the shuttle had (18000$/kg). I really don't see why you would call the price of 1.16B for the Saturn V as "preposterous" or "obviously out-of-range". The Saturn V weighs 3000 tons, the whole shuttle stack less then 2000 tons, and the shuttle was dead weight that had to be recovered and wasn't usable payload.

Comment: @Polygnome: I don't know the real numbers but I know enough to set an upper bound of 750 million dollars per production booster. It's the shuttle numbers that are all whacked to me.

Comment: @Joshua Where do you get an upper bound of 750m for? Do you have any source? And what exactly is your notably claim you want falsified? Spaceflight incurs these costs. Thats one of the major point of criticism of the Shuttle, its high cost per kg of payload (and at 1.16B, Saturn V would still have been twice as efficient as the shuttle, even if you take the low number of 450m / flight for the shuttle).

Comment: @Polygnome: If you'd actually evaluate what you read off Wikipedia; you could do the following calculation: 1.16b 110m / 185m -> 689m. That is; take off the cost for all the stuff for landing on the moon and evaluate as for a low earth orbit mission.

Comment: @Joshua I have no idea what those numbers are supposed to say. Whats "110m / 185m" supposed to be? Where do the 689m come from? Furthermore, from the text of your question, why do you think its wrong to include development cost? Those are costs that were paid, after all.